# Exception handling in the Spark streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have developed a Spark Streaming application which checkpoints a filestream. I need to stop my streaming application on any drive exception..my codes are as follow:

```
val fileStream=..
  fileStream.checkpoint(Duration(batchIntervalSeconds * 1000 * 5))

//initiate the chekpointing
fileStream.foreachRDD(r=> {
  try {
    r.count()
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => {
      ssc.stop(true, true)
    }

  }
}
)
```

However, I get the exception from the above code

```
 yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception:
java.io.NotSerializableException: DStream checkpointing has been enabled but the DStreams with their functions are not serializable
org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, value: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@45ae9d8b)
    - field (class: UnionStream$$anonfun$creatingFunc$3, name: ssc$1, type: class org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext)
    - object (class UnionStream$$anonfun$creatingFunc$3, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3, name: cleanedF$1, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3, <function2>)
    - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream, org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@12481647)
    - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData,
```

I am running my codes on yarn cluster mode..

Answer (score 2):

To stop a spark streaming application when an exception occurs inside a foreachRDD call, don't try to catch the exception inside foreachRDD. Instead wrap the ssc.awaitTermination call inside a try / catch block and call ssc.stop from there:

```
val ssc = createStreamingContext()        
ssc.start()
try {
  ssc.awaitTermination()
} catch {
  case e: Exception => 
    ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = true, stopGracefully = true)
    throw e // to exit with error condition
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is and where you learned about it?

Comment: I haven't done any spark programming in 3 years so I'm afraid I've forgotten why this is. I'm assuming an uncaught exception gets relayed back from the executor to the driver and gets thrown there. By catching it on the driver a coordinated clean shutdown is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to take the try{}catch out of forEachRDD and wrap the call to foreachrdd inside try+catch{}, something like this

```
 try {
//initiate the chekpointing
fileStream.foreachRDD(r=> {
    r.count()
  }
}
 } catch {
    case ex: Exception => {
      ssc.stop(true, true)
    }
)
```

from the exception it looks like spark is taking all the code inside foreachRDD block including exception handle which needs SparkStreamingContext and trying to serialize it so that it can send it to node that will handle the process on current RDD. Since SparkStreamingContext is not serializable its blowing up.

Comment: Can I ask a question? Do r.count() always run on the driver node? I need to get the exceptions just from Driver..

Comment: No whatever your doing inside foreachRDD would go to the node handling the task. But what you want is to stop the context in case of error and you can access context only from driver.